# Loud bangs and power outage

Tags: electrical-panel

8 to 10 very loud bangs over 2 hours with a short (5 to 10 second) loss of power. The bangs were very loud.
The bangs were from inside the house.

Comment: I can't help noticing that you marked this question with the specific tag "electrical panel".  Is this relating to your service panel? Red alert!  Can the main breaker be shut off Right Now, kept off indefinitely, pictures taken of the panel switches and labeling, and [edit]ed into this question?  Remember to take a flashlight with you as the power will be out!

Comment: Yes, can you shut off the main breaker and take some pictures of the main panel (including the labeling on the inside of the cover) with the aid of a flashlight please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This sounds like an emergency: get expert help now! Once things have settled down, give us more info, and you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I have had 8 bangs in a night but over a longer period than 2 hours.   But yea power was off for a while after that.